# upload size limit in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a page where user can register. He uploads a profile picture in the process. I want to limit the size but there is not much emphasis on codeigniter documentation except for $config['maxsize']. I tried the following but I don't get any messages. I set the size to 10 (KB) just for testing. Do I have to handle it somehow to get the message across to my view?

```
public function add_user()
    {


        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';        
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '10';
        //$config['max_width'] = '1024';
        //$config['max_height'] = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $fullImagePath;
        if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
          {
          if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
          {
            // set a $_POST value for 'image' that we can use later
...
```

By the way this code is in my Model.

Comment: why you are keeping it in your model ....?

Comment: I was just testing the feature..I know it should be in controller. I will migrate it later

Comment: Follow this link http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html when you exceed size specified in maxsize field CI will give error automatically........

Answer (score 4):

@Chetan Wadhwa,

Are you sure the size is in Bytes(Not in KB). Refer codeigniter documentation: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html, must be in KB.

Answer (score 1):

This Size is not in KB it is in Bytes so for 10KB you should write (10*1024) Bytes or "10240"

Comment: The CodeIgniter documentation states that max_size is in fact in KB.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle the error message CI will take care that in this case so please follow the [upload class tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) which specified in codeIgniter userguide.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class upload extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
}

function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }

}
}
?>
```