# Set Max Size in CodeIgniter File Upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I've used this private function to file upload in CodeIgniter Project. I've never set max_size in this function. Here, how to set max_size in this private function?

```
private function do_upload($value){
    $type = explode('.', $_FILES[$value]["name"]);
    $type = $type[count($type)-1];
    $url = "./assets/uploads/products/".uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;

    if(in_array($type, array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png")))

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$value]["tmp_name"]))

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$value]["tmp_name"], $url))

    return $url;

    return "";
}
```

Comment: are you asking how to check size of uploaded file or to set available size ?

Comment: If you would prefer  to use Codeigniter upload library, look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208096/upload-size-limit-in-codeigniter

Comment: I want to fix the size of the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get size of that file by $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'], 
for example:

```
$maxsize=2097152;
if(($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] >= $maxsize)) {
        $errors[] = 'File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes.';
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

just simply do this.

```
if($_FILES["my_file_name"]['size'] > 1900000){  //set my_file_name to yours <input type="file" name="my_file_name">

  echo "file is too large";

}else{

  echo "file meets the minimum size";   

}
```

if you want to set bigger upload size to your system, you need to go to **php.ini** file and change this.

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M; //change this to your desired size.
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a php.ini file at your websites base folder

and add following (2M = 2 megabyte you can add your desired size )

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M;
```

on it

Answer (score 0):

AS recommend: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html
2MB (or 2048 KB) So that:

```
$config['max_size'] = 1024 * 10; // <= 10Mb;
```

Answer (score 0):

**CodeIgniter 4** - set max size using 'max_size[]' in the validation rules arary of your controller:

```
public function upload(){
        $validationRule = [
            'userfile' => [
                'label' => 'Image File',
                'rules' => [
                    'uploaded[userfile]',
                    'is_image[userfile]',
                    'mime_in[userfile,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,image]',

                    'max_size[userfile,100]',// <<< Max file size here

                    'max_dims[userfile,1024,768]',
                ],
            ],
        ];

if (! $this->validate($validationRule)) {
   $data = ['errors' => $this->validator->getErrors()];
   return view('back_end/owners/upload_form', $data);
 }

}
```

See CodeIgniter 4 docs: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/validation.html?highlight=max_size